# Elastic search parse as object but found nested values

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, elasticsearch

I'm currently working on a project where I have a data stored from previous processing in a csv, and I'd like to give a try to ElasticSearch + Kibana to analyse my data*. The problem is I have a column with json values and some None values that I send with nested type. To clean the None I repalced it by 'null' but I get the following error:

```
Tried to parse field as object but found a concrete value
```

I think ES doesn't like fields which may have a 'NULL' or nested type in for a field. How may I solve this and keep the principle of a null value to allow filtering later? Thanks for the help :)

I'm using python and [eland module](https://eland.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/eland.pandas_to_eland.html) which deals with sending pandas dataframe to ES.

```
ES version:
'version': {'number': '7.7.0',
  'build_flavor': 'default',
  'build_type': 'deb',
  'build_hash': '81a1e9eda8e6183f5237786246f6dced26a10eaf',
  'build_date': '2020-05-12T02:01:37.602180Z',
  'build_snapshot': False,
  'lucene_version': '8.5.1',
  'minimum_wire_compatibility_version': '6.8.0',
  'minimum_index_compatibility_version': '6.0.0-beta1'},
 'tagline': 'You Know, for Search'}
```

## EDIT

I'm sending my data using the code extract below (python3), which is now working thanks to @Gibbs' answer

```py
INDEX_NAME = 'my_index'
DATA_PATH = './data4analysis.csv'
def csv_jsonconverter_todict(field):
    if not field:
        return {'null_value': 'NULL'}
    if "'" in field:  # cleaning if bad json column, ok for me
        field = field.replace("'", '"')
    try:
        return json.loads(field)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception('json.loads(field) failed on field= %s', field, exc_info=True)
        raise e


def loadNprepare_data(path, sep=';'):
    df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=sep, encoding='cp1252',
                     converters={'ffprobe': csv_jsonconverter_todict)

    # cleaning NaNs to avoid " json_parse_exception Non-standard token 'NaN'"
    df = df.applymap(lambda cell: 'null_value' if pd.isna(cell) or not cell else cell)
    return df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    es_client = Elasticsearch(hosts=[ES_HOST], http_compress=True)

    if es_client.indices.exists(INDEX_NAME):
        logger.info(f"deleting '{INDEX_NAME}' index...")
        res = es_client.indices.delete(index=INDEX_NAME)
        logger.info(f"response: '{res}'")

    # since we are running locally, use one shard and no replicas
    request_body = {
        "settings": {
            "number_of_shards": 1,
            "number_of_replicas": 0
        }
    }
    logger.info(f"creating '{INDEX_NAME}' index...")
    res = es_client.indices.create(index=INDEX_NAME, body=request_body)
    logger.info(f" response: '{res}'")

    logger.info("Sending data to ES")

    data = loadNprepare_data(DATA_PATH)
    try:
        el_df = eland.pandas_to_eland(data, es_client,
                                      es_dest_index=INDEX_NAME,
                                      es_if_exists='replace',
                                      es_type_overrides= {'ffprobe': 'nested'})
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('Elsatic Search error', exc_info=True)
        raise e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you defined a `type` for a column. And you are trying to insert string `'null'`  in that column.

Two different types are not supported. It will accept Null value if you do as mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html)

> > A null value cannot be indexed or searched. When a field is set to null, (or an empty array or an array of null values) it is treated as though that field has no values.

> > The null_value parameter allows you to replace explicit null values with the specified value so that it can be indexed and searched

Answer (score 0):

<disclosure: I'm maintainer of Eland and employed by Elastic>

Are you trying to import the DataFrame into Elasticsearch into an existing index? Otherwise it may be worth it to look at the mapping that Eland created for you and see which field is mapped to a type that you're not expecting. You may need to make certain fields for numerics "nullable" if you're planning on having null values in Elasticsearch.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch(<your cluster info>)
resp = es.indices.get_mapping("<your index>")
print(resp)
```

If you are able to post your index mapping and an example of the type of CSV rows you're inserting that'd go a long way in me being able to help you too